# Argon2 library that hashes passwords without a secret and with a random salt that doesn't appear parseable

Tags: python, argon2-ffi

I am looking at different alternatives to hash passwords in a Python app. First I was settling for Flask-bcrypt (https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-bcrypt), but then decided to use Argon2. The most popular Argon2 bindings for Python is argon2-cffi  (https://github.com/hynek/argon2-cffi).

According to its' docs (https://argon2-cffi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html), all I need to do is use 3 methods:

- `hash` to hash a password
- `verify` to compare a password to a hash
- `check_needs_rehash` to see if a password should be rehashed after a change in the hashing parameters

Two things puzzle me.

1) The salt is random, using `os.urandom`. I thus wonder if the `verify` method is somehow able to extract the salt from the hash? Or in other words, since I have no say in what the salt is and cannot save it, how can the `verify` method actually ever compare any password to a password that was hashed with a random salt? Am I supposed to somehow parse the salt from the return value of `hash` myself, and store it separately from the hashed value? Or is the hash supposed to be stored as is in the docs, untouched, and somehow Argon2 is capable of verifying a password against it? And if indeed Argon2 can extract the salt out of the hash, how is using a salt any safer in that case since a hostile entity who gets a hashed password should then also be able to extract the salt?

2) By default I do not supply any secret to the `hash` method and instead the password itself seems to be used as a secret. Is this secure? What are the downsides for me not supplying a secret to the hashing method?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> 1) The salt is random, using `os.urandom`. I thus wonder if the `verify` method is somehow able to extract the salt from the hash?

**The `hash` method returns a string that encodes the salt, the parameters, and the password hash itself, as shown in the documentation:**

```
>>> from argon2 import PasswordHasher
>>> ph = PasswordHasher()
>>> hash = ph.hash("s3kr3tp4ssw0rd")
>>> hash  
'$argon2id$v=19$m=102400,t=2,p=8$tSm+JOWigOgPZx/g44K5fQ$WDyus6py50bVFIPkjA28lQ'
>>> ph.verify(hash, "s3kr3tp4ssw0rd")
True
```

The format is summarized [in the Argon2 reference implementation](https://github.com/P-H-C/phc-winner-argon2/blob/4ac8640c2adc1257677d27d3f833c8d1ee68c7d2/src/encoding.c#L242-L252); perhaps there are other references.  In this case:

1. `$argon2id$...`

   The hash is Argon2id, which is the specific Argon2 variant that everyone should use (combining the side channel resistance of Argon2i with the more difficult-to-crack Argon2d).
2. `...$v=19$...`

   The version of the hash is 0x13 (19 decimal), meaning Argon2 v1.3, the version adopted by the [Password Hashing Competition](https://password-hashing.net).
3. `...$m=102400,t=2,p=8$...`

   The memory use is 100 MB (102400 KB), the time is 2 iterations, and the parallelism is 8 ways.
4. `...$tSm+JOWigOgPZx/g44K5fQ$...`

   The salt is `tSm+JOWigOgPZx/g44K5fQ` (base64), or `b5 29 be 24 e5 a2 80 e8  0f 67 1f e0 e3 82 b9 7d` (hexadecimal).
5. `...$WDyus6py50bVFIPkjA28lQ`

   The password hash itself is `WDyus6py50bVFIPkjA28lQ` (base64), or `58 3c ae b3 aa 72 e7 46  d5 14 83 e4 8c 0d bc 95` (hexadecimal).

The `verify` method takes this string and a candidate password, recomputes the password hash with all the encoded parameters, and compares it to the encoded password hash.

> And if indeed Argon2 can extract the salt out of the hash, how is using a salt any safer in that case since a hostile entity who gets a hashed password should then also be able to extract the salt?

**The purpose of the salt is to mitigate the batch advantage of multi-target attacks by simply being *different* for each user.**

- If everyone used the *same* salt, then an adversary trying to find the *first of $n$ passwords* given hashes would need to spend only about $1/n$ the cost that an adversary trying to find *a single specific password* given its hash would have to spend.  Alternatively, an adversary could accelerate breaking *individual* passwords by doing an expensive precomputation (rainbow tables).
- But if everyone uses a *different* salt, then that batch advantage or precomputation advantage goes away.

Choosing the salt uniformly at random among 32-byte strings is just an easy way to guarantee every user has a distinct salt.  In principle, one could imagine an authority handing out everyone in the world a consecutive number to use as their Argon2 salt, but that system doesn't scale very well—I don't just mean that *your application* could use the counting authority, but *every application in the world* would have to use the *same* counting authority, and I think the Count is too busy at Sesame Street to take on that job.

> 2) By default I do not supply any secret to the `hash` method and instead the password itself seems to be used as a secret. Is this secure? What are the downsides for me not supplying a secret to the hashing method?

**Generally the password *is* the secret: if someone knows the password then they're supposed to be able to log in; if they don't know the password, they're supposed to be shown the door!**

That said, Argon2 *also* supports a secret key, which is separate from the salt and separate from the password.

If there is a meaningful security boundary between your *password database* and your *application* so that it's plausible an adversary might compromise one but not the other, then the *application* can pick a uniform random 32-byte string as a secret key, and use that with Argon2 so that the password hash is a *secret* function of the secret password.

That way, an adversary who dumps the password database but not the application's secret key won't even be able to *test* a guess for a password because they don't know the secret key needed to compute a password's hash.

Answer (score 2):

The output of hash is actually an encoding of the hash, hash parameters, and salt. You don't need to do anything special with it, just store it normally.

Argon2 is a password hashing algorithm. It doesn't (usually) require any secret. This is secure by design. It's possible to use it with a secret value in addition to the password, which should almost never add any security. It's also possible to use it as a key derivation function, which is almost always wasteful. Neither of these things would reduce security, but they're unnecessary so don't bother.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However I am still left wondering what's the point of even using a salt when hashing the password, since if the salt is in the encoded hash that I will store so that any hostile party that get their hands on the encoded hash also then get their hands on the salt?

Comment: It means that two users with the same password get different salts, and thus different hashes. So an attacker has to crack each password individually. Ideally users would have 10-word Diceware passphrases and none of this would be needed, but that's not realistic. People will pick bad passwords, so we mitigate that as best we can.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but pyargon2 is a valid alternative to overcome this. First to install the repo:

`pip install pyargon2`

then use:

```
from pyargon2 import hash
password = 'a strong password'
salt = 'a unique salt'
hex_encoded_hash = hash(password, salt)
```

More information:

https://github.com/ultrahorizon/pyargon2

Credit: https://github.com/jwsi