# How to implement HMAC verification with AES mode CBC

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, aes, encryption-symmetric

I'm working on a project where I have to make a password manager. I'm using AES in CBC mode and I have to implement HMAC for authentication. This is my encryption function:

```
def encrypt_password(master_password, password, salt, iv):
    key = scrypt(master_password, salt, 16, N=2**14, r = AES.block_size, p = 1)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    encoded = base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(pad(password, AES.block_size)))
    return encoded
```

and decryption function:

```
def decrypt_password(master_password, encoded, salt, iv):
    encoded = base64.b64decode(encoded)
    key = scrypt(master_password, salt, 16, N=2**14, r = AES.block_size, p = 1)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    decrypted = cipher.decrypt(encoded)
    decrypted = unpad(decrypted, AES.block_size)
    return decrypted
```

My problem is that I don't have a clue how to implement authentication here, can anyone please give me any tips? Thank you.

Comment: We don't encrypt passwords we use password hashing algorithms like PBKDF2, Argon2, etc. Why do you need to encrypt them?

Comment: I ment that, my terminology is off.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58431973/1820553

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Did you see the code? hash the password and verify. Doesn't you need that?

Comment: @kelalaka I guess OP wants message authentication [for example](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) with an encrypt-then-MAC scheme.

Comment: @ArtjomB.You may right. In that case [How to use SHA256-HMAC in python code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51861438/1820553)